# parse XML into a table works in all browsers except IE

Tags: javascript, xml, parsing, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I am using JavaScript to parse XML into a table and display it on click. This works great everywhere except IE. I can't use PHP for this because of company regs.

I know that IE parses XML differently, but I can't seem to get any of the IE fixes to work within my script. This won't work in any version of IE. I would also like to eventually search the tables, which I have working in chrome and Firefox.

link to example: https://www.theborgata.com/assets/test/view-winners.html

```js
function loadXMLDoc(a) {
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      myFunction(this);
    }
  };
  xmlhttp.open("GET", a, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
  xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;

}

function myFunction(xml) {
  var i;
  var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  var table = "<tr><th>Account #</th><th>Name</th></tr>";
  var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("record");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    table += "<tr><td>" +
      x[i].getElementsByTagName("Account")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
      "</td><td>" +
      x[i].getElementsByTagName("Name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
      "</td></tr>";
  }

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;
  document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = table;
  document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = table;

}
```

```html
<!--button 1-->  
<button class="w3-bar-item w3-button testbtn w3-padding-16" 
onclick="openCity(event,'week1');loadXMLDoc('week-16.xml');">week 1 - 
9.12</button>

<!--button 2-->
<button class="w3-bar-item w3-button testbtn w3-padding-16" 
onclick="openCity(event,'week2');loadXMLDoc('week-17.xml');">week 2 - 
9.19</button>

<!--button 3-->
<button class="w3-bar-item w3-button testbtn w3-padding-16" 
onclick="openCity(event,'week3');loadXMLDoc('week-18.xml');">week 3 - 
9.26</button>

<!--div to show on button click 1-->
<div id="week1" class="w3-container city w3-animate-opacity">
<div class="w3-responsive w3-card-4">
<table id="demo" class="w3-table w3-striped w3-bordered"></table>
</div>
</div>

<!--div to show on button click 2-->
<div id="week2" class="w3-container city w3-animate-opacity">
<div class="w3-responsive w3-card-4">
<table id="demo2" class="w3-table w3-striped w3-bordered"></table>
</div>
</div>

<!--div to show on button click 3-->
<div id="week3" class="w3-container city w3-animate-opacity">
<div class="w3-responsive w3-card-4">
<table id="demo3" class="w3-table w3-striped w3-bordered"></table>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What version of IE are you having problems with?

Comment: Assuming your xmlhttp works fine, please click edit and then `[<>]` and create a [mcve] with JUST the HTML, the XML and the  myFunction. We do not need the rest of the code to test if your parsing works

Comment: all versions of IE

Comment: I updated the above with a link to the page & cleaned up my code

Answer (score 0):

Try to refer an example below which i modified similar to your code and it is working fine in Internet Explorer and other browsers.

**parse_xml_1.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<button onclick="displayCD();">Show Data</button>
<div id='showCD'></div>
<table id="demo" border=1></table>

<script>

function displayCD() {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            myFunction(this);
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "cd_catalog.xml", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

function myFunction(xml) {
    var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML; 
    x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CD");
var table = "<tr><th>ARTIST</th><th>TITLE</th><th>YEAR</th></tr>";
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {

      table += "<tr><td>" +
      x[i].getElementsByTagName("ARTIST")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
      "</td>" +
      "<td>" +
      x[i].getElementsByTagName("TITLE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
      "</td>" +
      "<td>" +
      x[i].getElementsByTagName("YEAR")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
      "</td></tr>";
    }
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**cd_catalog.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<CATALOG>
<CD>
<TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE>
<ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST>
<COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
<COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
<PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
<YEAR>1985</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
<TITLE>Hide your heart</TITLE>
<ARTIST>Bonnie Tyler</ARTIST>
<COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
<COMPANY>CBS Records</COMPANY>
<PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
<YEAR>1988</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
<TITLE>Greatest Hits</TITLE>
<ARTIST>Dolly Parton</ARTIST>
<COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
<COMPANY>RCA</COMPANY>
<PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
<YEAR>1982</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
<TITLE>Still got the blues</TITLE>
<ARTIST>Gary Moore</ARTIST>
<COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
<COMPANY>Virgin records</COMPANY>
<PRICE>10.20</PRICE>
<YEAR>1990</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
<TITLE>Eros</TITLE>
<ARTIST>Eros Ramazzotti</ARTIST>
<COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY>
<COMPANY>BMG</COMPANY>
<PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
<YEAR>1997</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
<TITLE>One night only</TITLE>
<ARTIST>Bee Gees</ARTIST>
<COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
<COMPANY>Polydor</COMPANY>
<PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
<YEAR>1998</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
<TITLE>Sylvias Mother</TITLE>
<ARTIST>Dr.Hook</ARTIST>
<COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
<COMPANY>CBS</COMPANY>
<PRICE>8.10</PRICE>
<YEAR>1973</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
<TITLE>Maggie May</TITLE>
<ARTIST>Rod Stewart</ARTIST>
<COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
<COMPANY>Pickwick</COMPANY>
<PRICE>8.50</PRICE>
<YEAR>1990</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
<TITLE>Romanza</TITLE>
<ARTIST>Andrea Bocelli</ARTIST>
<COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY>
<COMPANY>Polydor</COMPANY>
<PRICE>10.80</PRICE>
<YEAR>1996</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
<TITLE>When a man loves a woman</TITLE>
<ARTIST>Percy Sledge</ARTIST>
<COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
<COMPANY>Atlantic</COMPANY>
<PRICE>8.70</PRICE>
<YEAR>1987</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
<TITLE>Black angel</TITLE>
<ARTIST>Savage Rose</ARTIST>
<COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY>
<COMPANY>Mega</COMPANY>
<PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
<YEAR>1995</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
<TITLE>1999 Grammy Nominees</TITLE>
<ARTIST>Many</ARTIST>
<COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
<COMPANY>Grammy</COMPANY>
<PRICE>10.20</PRICE>
<YEAR>1999</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
<TITLE>For the good times</TITLE>
<ARTIST>Kenny Rogers</ARTIST>
<COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
<COMPANY>Mucik Master</COMPANY>
<PRICE>8.70</PRICE>
<YEAR>1995</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
<TITLE>Big Willie style</TITLE>
<ARTIST>Will Smith</ARTIST>
<COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
<COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
<PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
<YEAR>1997</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
<TITLE>Tupelo Honey</TITLE>
<ARTIST>Van Morrison</ARTIST>
<COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
<COMPANY>Polydor</COMPANY>
<PRICE>8.20</PRICE>
<YEAR>1971</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
<TITLE>Soulsville</TITLE>
<ARTIST>Jorn Hoel</ARTIST>
<COUNTRY>Norway</COUNTRY>
<COMPANY>WEA</COMPANY>
<PRICE>7.90</PRICE>
<YEAR>1996</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
<TITLE>The very best of</TITLE>
<ARTIST>Cat Stevens</ARTIST>
<COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
<COMPANY>Island</COMPANY>
<PRICE>8.90</PRICE>
<YEAR>1990</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
<TITLE>Stop</TITLE>
<ARTIST>Sam Brown</ARTIST>
<COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
<COMPANY>A and M</COMPANY>
<PRICE>8.90</PRICE>
<YEAR>1988</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
<TITLE>Bridge of Spies</TITLE>
<ARTIST>T'Pau</ARTIST>
<COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
<COMPANY>Siren</COMPANY>
<PRICE>7.90</PRICE>
<YEAR>1987</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
<TITLE>Private Dancer</TITLE>
<ARTIST>Tina Turner</ARTIST>
<COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
<COMPANY>Capitol</COMPANY>
<PRICE>8.90</PRICE>
<YEAR>1983</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
<TITLE>Midt om natten</TITLE>
<ARTIST>Kim Larsen</ARTIST>
<COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY>
<COMPANY>Medley</COMPANY>
<PRICE>7.80</PRICE>
<YEAR>1983</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
<TITLE>Pavarotti Gala Concert</TITLE>
<ARTIST>Luciano Pavarotti</ARTIST>
<COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
<COMPANY>DECCA</COMPANY>
<PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
<YEAR>1991</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
<TITLE>The dock of the bay</TITLE>
<ARTIST>Otis Redding</ARTIST>
<COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
<COMPANY>Stax Records</COMPANY>
<PRICE>7.90</PRICE>
<YEAR>1968</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
<TITLE>Picture book</TITLE>
<ARTIST>Simply Red</ARTIST>
<COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY>
<COMPANY>Elektra</COMPANY>
<PRICE>7.20</PRICE>
<YEAR>1985</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
<TITLE>Red</TITLE>
<ARTIST>The Communards</ARTIST>
<COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
<COMPANY>London</COMPANY>
<PRICE>7.80</PRICE>
<YEAR>1987</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
<TITLE>Unchain my heart</TITLE>
<ARTIST>Joe Cocker</ARTIST>
<COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
<COMPANY>EMI</COMPANY>
<PRICE>8.20</PRICE>
<YEAR>1987</YEAR>
</CD>
</CATALOG>
```

Output in IE 11:

[image]

**Note: User need to host this example on any web server. for testing purpose, I hosted it on IIS server. If user try to run this example directly than it may give CORS related errors.**